# Angular Component gets looped

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components

Im building an Angular application and my navbar gets looped.
My problem is, that if I am on /home, the navbar.component.html components gets looped and i see 2 among each other. How can I solve this

```
import {Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from "./home/home.component";
import {AdminComponent} from "./admin/admin.component";

export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', title: 'Home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'admin', title: 'Admin', component: AdminComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'home'},
];
```

app.modules.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {NavbarComponent} from "./navbar/navbar.component";
import {AdminComponent} from "./admin/admin.component";
import {RouterLink, RouterModule, RouterOutlet} from "@angular/router";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AdminComponent, NavbarComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterLink, RouterOutlet, RouterModule],
  exports: [AdminComponent, NavbarComponent, CommonModule, RouterLink, RouterOutlet, RouterModule]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ui</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<app-home></app-home>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
</html>
```

home.component.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

navbar.component.html

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a routerLink="/home" >Home</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/news">News</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/admin">Admin</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I tried changing the router outlet many times and changing where I use which component but I cant bring it to work.

Heres the whole repository: [https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/leningl-bzz/Import-Project](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/leningl-bzz/Import-Project)

Comment: sounds like there is a circular reference somewhere.  Can you post your home component code.  I had a similar issue where the nav bar was being imported in more than one palce

Comment: I added a stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/leningl-bzz/Import-Project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### UPDATE

The reason you are getting this problem is because, you have bootstrap `HomeComponent` which is ok, but you are referencing the same home component in routing, which is the default route, this is why the navbar is coming twice.

The fix for this issue, is to define an `AppComponent` which will act as the root component, which will store the navbar and load the child components inside it!

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from '../app.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AppModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

app html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ui</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

main.ts

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { config } from './app/app.config.server';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app/app.component';

const bootstrap = () => bootstrapApplication(AppComponent,  config);

export default bootstrap;
```

main.server.ts

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/leningl-bzz/Import-Project)

---

Can you modify the `index.html` so that it only contains the main bootstrapped component, either the one used in `bootstrap` array of modules or the component used in `bootstrapApplication`!

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ui</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<app-home></app-home> <!-- assuming this is the bootstrap main component of your application! -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did this and the navbar is still looping sadly

Comment: @Lukas is it possible to replicate the issue on a stackblitz where the issue happens

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/leningl-bzz/Import-Project

Answer (score 0):

You have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` 2 times on page - 1 in `index.html`, and 1 in `home.component.html`, hence route is rendered 2 times.

You also have a route with `HomeComponent`, which is rendered by `router-outlet` and renders itself as well(because `HomeComponent` contains `router-outlet`). I suggest you to move layout(navbar and `router-outlet`) from `HomeComponent` to `AppComponent`, and leave in `HomeComponent` only home page content. Also you may want to check that `router-outlet` is met in your files only once, and components which can be rendered by `router-outlet`(those which are met in your routes) don't contain `router-outlet` or child components which contain `router-outlet`.

If you want pages to have different layouts, you should move layout logic to pages(you can DRY layout logic, by moving layout logic to some `SomePageLayoutComponent` with `TemplateRef<SomeTemplateContext>` inputs, and using those layout component in your pages)

Comment: I removed the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` from the index.html but it's still looping. I want this layout on every page.

Comment: @Lukas I updated my answer:


You also have a route with `HomeComponent`, which is rendered by `router-outlet` and renders itself as well(because `HomeComponent` contains `router-outlet`). I suggest you to move layout(navbar and `router-outlet`) from `HomeComponent` to `AppComponent`, and leave in `HomeComponent` only home page content. Also you may want to check that `router-outlet` is met in your files only once, and components which can be rendered by `router-outlet`(those which are met in your routes) don't contain `router-outlet` or child components which contain `router-outlet`.